# If the certificate CN is different from a server's public DNS name, are SANs the way to go?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, hostname

I am aware that hostname verification is required for an SSL handshake to be successful, and is vital for security reasons (i.e. MiTM attacks). That said, AWS automatically assigns public DNS names for an EC2 instance and often times companies want to generate a certificate for a web service using a CN more pertinent to their company i.e. dev.contoso.com. And clients will access this service via dev.contoso.com.

If this is the case then, my understanding is that in an ssl handshake the EC2 would present a cert with the name dev.contoso.com but the actual server name would be something of the form ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. And that would cause hostname verification to fail...right? Even if the server is signed by a CA which the client already trusts.

Is the right solution here to use SANs and simply specify the desired hostname as an alternate name in the certificate, or is there a more advisable solution. Please correct my understanding on this process if I am wrong.

Comment: Huh?  If the clients are accessing the service via dev.contoso.com, that's the host name as far as they are concerned.  They don't know or care that the server also has another name.  (Edit: I suppose a client *could* do a reverse DNS lookup and complain if the name doesn't match, but I don't think that ever happens?  I mean, it would break pretty much everything.)

Comment: You can have many DNS names pointing to a given IP/host.  The name amazon uses, is the name amazon uses. You don't have to use that out in the world.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Then I think my understanding needs a little correcting then because I was under the impression that during a TLS handshake the client will check the CN (or SANs) in the certificate presented by the host and if it doesn't find anything that matches the domain in the URL then it will fail hostname verification. I thought this happened by default, per IETF standards, and in enforced by the browser....no?

Comment: If I've understood the scenario correctly, you have asked the client to connect to dev.contoso.com.  So that's the name that it will be expecting to find in the certificate.  Unless I've misread the question, that's also the name that is *in* the certificate, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Zoredache Hmm, so the public DNS name assigned to an EC2 instance, by AWS (as in the one I'd use to PuTTy or RDP to an EC2), can be different from the CN in the certificate presented by the web service? If I have that correct then is it because SANs can be provided in the cert? Or would SANs still not even be necessary?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ahh not quite. In my scenario the dev.contoso.com is NOT what would be in the certificate. It's what would be *expected*, yes, but not what will actually be in the certificate's CN. That's why I am asking if SANs are the correct way to work around that.

Comment: But why would you create the certificate with the wrong CN?  Are you using some sort of automated certificate generation system?

Comment: Hehe, well, you'd have to ask the client that. However, A. Yes, they do auto-create their own certs. And B. to me it would make sense if you're a company and you want your certificate to reflect your company's name rather than an AWS one so I imagine that's partially the reason too. I'm sure it's quite common.

Comment: Yes, you typically want the certificate to reflect your company's name, so that's the CN you should be using.  So let me rephrase: why would you generate a certificate containing the AWS name as the CN?

Comment: Well that isn't what they're doing. They *are* creating the cert with the company's name but when you create the EC2 instance it is going to automatically get assigned a public DNS name like ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.amazonaws.com. So I was wondering if this matters when clients access the server, that the certificate CN (company's name) doesn't match the public DNS record (ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.amazonaws.com) used to access it. i.e. As a client I browse to http://ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XX.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 but the certificate contains contoso.com in the CN.

Comment: Most browsers and then probably HTTP libraries do not care too much anymore about what is in the CN because per specifications what counts for certificates bound to devices is what is in the SAN section.